# Qt5Nfc not found - CMake

Tags: qt, cmake, nfc

I try to compile a qt app on Manjaro Linux and I am getting this error:

```sh
CMake Error at /usr/lib64/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Nfc" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5NfcConfig.cmake
    qt5nfc-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Nfc" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Nfc_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5Nfc"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Manjaro (and possible other distros) you have to install this package: `qt5-connectivity`